# Beamer: description item with tiny font

Tags: beamer, fontsize

In *Beamer*, I use the following code `\setbeamerfont{description item}{size=\tiny}` but it seem **not** to work. How can I make *description* items use *tiny* as *fontsize*?

Comment: Perhaps `\setbeamerfont{itemize item}{size=\tiny}`?

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino: This also applies to `itemize`. Is it possible to apply it to only certain ones by using options like `\begin{itemize}[options here]`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Regarding the 2nd post, I try `\begin{itemize}[size=\tiny]` but it does **not** seem to work.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: I want the output of `{\tiny \begin{itemize}\item[1] Item~1 \end{itemize}}` dont know why but `\setbeamerfont{itemize item}{size=\tiny}` does **not** change the font for me. It just changes the size of the itemize numbering.

Comment: So, if the problem is not the numbering, this is a question that Marco answered quite recently, see: [Changing color and fonts of itemize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121720/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: I guess, you suggest me using `\begin{itemize}[before=\tiny]`. Okay, I could make it work with `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the preamble. Thank you.

Comment: If the problem is solved do you mind if we close this as duplicate of the other Q/A?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino In my opinion, this should not be a duplicate. Using the `enumitem` package with `beamer` is not recommended; in fact, it *shouldn't* be done. This question deserves a proper `beamer` way of doing what was requested. I've voted for reopening.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I just did a stupid thing, since it's true that `beamer` redefines completely those environments. I would have voted myself to reopen it, but it's already.

Comment: `\setbeamerfont{description item}{size=\tiny}` works fine for me. In `\item[foo] bar` the item `foo` is typeset tiny.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I wouldn't say it was stupid. In any case, as Alan Munn and then egreg noticed in comments, this is indeed a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73933

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TeX Live 2013 in a Linux your code work *for the labels*. To change *only* the font size of the text you can simply put `\tiny` just before of the first item. To do this  automatically every time, you can use the  solution cited by Alan Munn:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{description}{\tiny}
```

Or you can redefine the `description` environment, or better, simply define a new environment so you can use also the  original description:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\newenvironment{tynidesc}{
\setbeamerfont{description item}{size=\tiny}
\begin{description}\tiny}{\end{description}}

Scriptsize labels and large font in text    
\setbeamerfont{description item}{size=\scriptsize}
\begin{description}
\Large
\item[test] test    
\item[test] test 
\end{description}

Large labels and scriptsize fontin text 

\setbeamerfont{description item}{size=\Large}
\begin{description}
\scriptsize
\item[test] test    
\item[test] test 
\end{description}

\setbeamerfont{description item}{size=\normalsize}

The \texttt{tynidesc} environment   

\begin{tynidesc}
\item[test] test    
\item[test] test 
\end{tynidesc}

Normal \texttt{description} environment 

\begin{description}
\item[test] test    
\item[test] test 
\end{description}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

Comment: Notice that this only changes the font size of the *label* of the description, not its text. If the OP wants to change the text itself, then they need to use this solution: [Beamer and description environment text size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73933) (in which case the question is a duplicate, I should think.)

Comment: @AlanMunn, I see. Answer changed.

Comment: With your definition, `tynidesc` is not overlay-aware.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina. It is true, but if required you can still use overlays directly in the items.