# Changing color and fonts of itemize

Tags: fonts, lists, color

How can I change the font and color of a particular command in a LaTeX document?

For example I want all the text that follows the `\item` tag to be gray and the font should be different from the rest of the document , which i can specify ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This link might also be helpful: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_colours_in_LaTeX

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To manipulate list-environments to package `enumitem` is really suitable. With the option `before` you can specify your color and font which is local to the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{itemize}[before=\color{gray}\sffamily]
 \item Text in itemize with another color
 \item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... But i wanted to use a font of which i have a .ttf file ... How can that be done ?

Comment: @user1697007: What's the question? How to use a ttf file?

Comment: i wanted to use a particular font and color for the \itemize command .. 
i am now able to apply color as decribed above ..
but i want to use a different font .. 
i have ttf file for that font and also i installed that font on my machine ... I am using MAC and Texshop ...
So all i want now is to use a font for which i have the ttf file for the \itemize command ..

Comment: @user1697007: Your aim is to use a ttf file. This wasn't part of your original question. A ttf-file can't be used directly with LaTeX expect you are using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Then you can work `fontspec` and the provided command: `\newfontfamily`

Comment: yes ... sorry for the confusion ... 
Thanks .. i will try this ...